# Two objects from singleton

Tags: java, android

I want to make two objects from the following class and have stored two arraylist as well, as a matter of fact I want to store two variations of the same type in singleton

I call it by

```
CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();
```

in different Activities but encounter problem due to referring to the same object (arraylist)

```
 public class CrimeLab {
    private static final String TAG = "CrimeLab";
    private static final String FILENAME = "crimes.json";

    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;
    private CriminalIntentJSONSerializer mSerializer;

    private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;
    private Context mAppContext;

    private CrimeLab(Context appContext) {
        mAppContext = appContext;
        mSerializer = new CriminalIntentJSONSerializer(mAppContext, FILENAME);

        try {
            mCrimes = mSerializer.loadCrimes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mCrimes = new ArrayList<Crime>();
        }
    }

    public static CrimeLab get(Context c) {
        if (sCrimeLab == null) {
            sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(c.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sCrimeLab;
    }

    public Crime getCrime(int id) {
        for (Crime c : mCrimes) {
            if (c.getId() == (id))
                return c;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addCrime(Crime c) {
        mCrimes.add(c);
        saveCrimes();
    }

    public ArrayList<Crime> getCrimes() {
        return mCrimes;
    }

    public void deleteCrime(Crime c) {
        mCrimes.remove(c);
        saveCrimes();
    }

    public boolean saveCrimes() {
        try {
            mSerializer.saveCrimes(mCrimes);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: **"encounter problem due to referring to the same object (arraylist)"** : Your problem isn't clear - what specifically isn't working the way you expect it to?

Comment: I want to have Crimelab handle two arraylists, I cannot make reference to different Crimelab object in different Activites by calling : 'CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();'

Comment: @HoseinIT : You have used a singleton pattern which means there will only ever be one instance of your `CrimeLab` object and it will only ever have a single `ArrayList`. If you want multiple instances then ditch the singleton pattern (remove the `get()` method approach) and simply create instances using `new`.

Comment: If you're trying to follow the book this code comes from you should think why you're going against what they're doing. The whole point is to be able to use it across activities with a single data store.

Comment: @chief-two-pencils that right, and i want to customize it in order to have two  arrays accessed from other activities where Crimes were Added. any idea? am I going the right thing ?

Comment: But the question is - what' s the need or benefit of doing that? Are they going to also serialize to different locations. I'm confused why you want two stores consisting of the same type. That'll lead to inconsistent data.

Comment: @chief-two-pencils I have two activities to show different array of the same type (Crime). one list shows the local Crimes and the other shows the Online ones, How is that? how to do that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer it now because it's been put on hold. If you edit the post to better reflect what you're doing I'll vote to reopen. You need to explain that you want to store two variations of the same type in singleton. You simply can't have two instances of that class the way it's written and having gone through that book I can say you'll have some refactoring to do to make it work. I have an easy way to do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Issue comes from using static variable sCrimeLab. When you pass other getActivity() to CrimeLab.get you are updating (change) first object. Cause you not explain why you need to do it that way I sugest change method body to:

```
public static CrimeLab get(Context c) {
    return new CrimeLab(c.getApplicationContext());
}
```

or if it has to stay the way it is, change way how you are getting this class to:

```
CrimeLab crimeLab = new CrimeLab(getActivity());
crimeLab.getCrimes();
```

Comment: The reason I need it to handle two arraylist of 'Crime' is that I am showing two kinds of 'Crime', one Local and the other is fetched from server. But I face error of Nullpointerexception since it only refer to the local arraylist @maque